# Javascript Code to display series user input element

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to display series of numbers from 1 to 10 entered by user in textbox within the same page one number below the other. Also multiple of 3's should be in red colour.

```
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function testVariable() {
      var strText = document.getElementById("textone").value;
      var result = strText;
      document.getElementById('spanResult').textContent = result;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body> <input type="text" id="textone" /> <button onclick="testVariable()">Submit</button> <br /> <span id="spanResult"> </span> </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have tried below code.Not sure with multiple inputs and colour change
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function testVariable() {
            var strText = document.getElementById("textone").value;          

            var result = strText ;
            document.getElementById('spanResult').textContent = result;
           
             
        }
       
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
    <input type="text" id="textone" />
    
    <button  onclick="testVariable()">Submit</button> <br />
    <span id="spanResult">

    </span>
   
     
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, you might want to use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent` so that when a new element is created you can apply the `red` class to it:

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function testVariable() {
      var strText = document.getElementById("textone").value;
      var element = document.createElement("span");
      element.innerHTML = strText + "<br />";
      if (Number(strText)%3 == 0)
        element.classList.add("red");
      document.getElementById('spanResult').innerHTML += element.outerHTML;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="textone" /> <button onclick="testVariable()">Submit</button>
  <br />
  <span id="spanResult">
</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.It worked (colour change) for 3,6,15 but not for 6,9..

Comment: @bhagyashreejamdar I have updated the code, please have a look

Comment: It works for numbers entered in multiples of 3 (in any order) not exactly for numbers which are actual multiple of 3

Comment: @bhagyashreejamdar what do you mean by _actual multiple of 3_?

Comment: Its working.Thankyou so much

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a series like this or something else ?

```js
    function testVariable() {
      var strText = document.getElementById("textone").value;
      var result = strText;
      for(var i =1; i <= 10 ; i++){
      
       var disp = result * i;
       document.getElementById('spanResult').textContent  +=disp +' ';
      // console.log(i);
      }
      
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
 
</head>

<body> <input type="text" id="textone" /> <button onclick="testVariable()">Submit</button> <br /> <span id="spanResult"> </span> </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I wish to display every number entered in textbox , not a series of 1 to 10

Answer (score 0):

```js
// get a reference to the container element
const container = document.getElementById('listOfNumbersContainer');
// get a reference to the button and listen for 'click' events

const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let val = document.getElementById('numberInputElement').value; // retrieve the value of the input element

  // create a new div element
  // and append the user input 
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = val;

  // add the css class .is-red to the element if the value is a multiple of 3
  if (val % 3 === 0) {
    div.classList.add('is-red');
  }

  // add the element to the container
  container.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
div.is-red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numberInputElement" /><button>
Submit
</button>
<div id="listOfNumbersContainer">
  <!-- this is the place where the elements are appended -->
</div>
```